# Ruby on Rails, Form data not adding to the database via sql

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When placing an order on my ruby site only half of the information is added to the database. 
When I submit the form the server returns the following:

```
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bKcYiOq93T301ty4av2yyAqr4kKY11nn8I7qP7SWKmVgs/qgRmGcf82m5nAdnP1QqlvRFX8vjiSXa7dD4temwg==", "order"=>{"name"=>"Bruce Clay", "email"=>"bruce@dia.com", "address"=>"12", "city"=>"chippenham", "postcode"=>"kt12 3pw"}, "DeliveryDates.DeliveryConfirm"=>"false", "DeliveryDates.DeliveryDisagree"=>"True", "DeliveryDates.DeliveryDisagreeMessage"=>"", "ddate1"=>"20/04/2017", "ddate2"=>"25/04/2017", "ddate3"=>"23/04/2017", "card-identifier"=>"7FA7C55A-D3B3-45AC-AA82-D8850CD1E715"}
```

The information gets inserted apart from the ddates options.

```
SQL (9.9ms)  INSERT INTO `orders` (`name`, `email`, `address`, `city`, `postcode`, `buyer_id`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Bruce Claypot', 'bruce@dia.com', '12', 'chippenham', 'kt12 3pw', 1, 51.3862775, -0.3865515, '2017-04-18 12:50:21', '2017-04-18 12:50:21')
```

The orders controller has the following params :

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:name, :email, :address, :city, :county, :postcode, :ddate1, :ddate2, :ddate3)
end
```

and under def create :

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)
```

I'm really lost as to what is causing this issue as I have tried changing the params options but nothing will work.

Thanks for your help.

ADDED order model.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :product_items, dependent: :destroy 
     has_many :statuses

    validates :name, :email, :address, :city, :postcode, presence: true


    geocoded_by :postcode

# def address
#   [address, postcode].compact.join(', ')
# end# can also be an IP address
after_validation :geocode# auto-fetch coordinates

    def add_product_items_from_basket(basket)
        basket.product_items.each do |item|
            item.basket_id = nil
            product_items << item
        end
    end

    def total_price
        product_items.map(&:total_price).sum
    end

STATUSES = ['pending', 'offered', 'accepted', 'declined', 'returned', 'completed', 'canceled', 'refunded']
validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => STATUSES,
          :message => "{{value}} must be in #{STATUSES.join ','}"

end
```

Order Form script being used.

```
 <input class="text"  id="ddate1" name="ddate1" type="text" value=""><img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="../assets/calendar.png" alt="Select date" title="Select date">
                    </div>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DeliveryDates.DeliveryDateFirst" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </th>
                <script>
    $('#order_ddate1').ready(function(){
           var date_input=$('input[name="ddate1"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
      var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
      var options={
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        startDate: "+2d",
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
      };
      date_input.datepicker(options);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: you should fix your `order_params` functions body as,
`params.require(:order).permit(:name, :email, :address, :city, :postcode, :buyer_id, :latitude, :longitude)` or sth similar to this.

Comment: under order_params action `buyer_id`, `latitude`, `longitude` attributes are missing, try adding these

Comment: @SanjuBMyh I have added these extras and they process correctly, however, the ddate ones are still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set up your strong params as:

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:name, :email, :address, :city, :county, :postcode, :ddate1, :ddate2, :ddate3)
end
```

Which indicates that you permit `ddate1, ddate2 and ddate3` from inside the order object i.e. they should be inside the order hash while 
your parameters shows that they are outside the require object `order`

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bKcYiOq93T301ty4av2yyAqr4kKY11nn8I7qP7SWKmVgs/qgRmGcf82m5nAdnP1QqlvRFX8vjiSXa7dD4temwg==", "order"=>{"name"=>"Bruce Clay", "email"=>"bruce@dia.com", "address"=>"12", "city"=>"chippenham", "postcode"=>"kt12 3pw"}, "DeliveryDates.DeliveryConfirm"=>"false", "DeliveryDates.DeliveryDisagree"=>"True", "DeliveryDates.DeliveryDisagreeMessage"=>"", "ddate1"=>"20/04/2017", "ddate2"=>"25/04/2017", "ddate3"=>"23/04/2017", "card-identifier"=>"7FA7C55A-D3B3-45AC-AA82-D8850CD1E715"}
```

You need to put them in view like you've done with other attributes `name, email etc` 
preferably use them as:

```
<%= f.text_field :ddate1, class="your_class" %>
```

where f is your form object iterator.

My guess is that you're using html syntax to generate form elements for `ddate1, ddate2, ddate3`. Please change them

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer. in the form, I have been using a script taken from the Asp.net version of the website that I am trying to recreate. Thanks for your help, I will try and change it.

Comment: Adding this to the form **name="order[ddate1]"**  instead of  name="ddate1" fixed the issue.